# Does every compact metric space have a finite basis?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, second-countable

Let $M$ be a compact metric space. Then the collection $\mathscr{U}=\{B(x,\frac1n):x\in M, n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ forms an open cover of $M.$ Let $\mathscr{B}_0$ be a finite sub-cover extract from $\mathscr{U}$. We can easily prove that $\mathscr{B}_0$ is a (finite) sub-basis for the topology on $M$.
Does $\mathscr{B}_0$ provide a finite basis for the metric topology on $M$?

Comment: The only metric spaces with finite bases are the finite discrete metric spaces.

Comment: Thank you. So, what is the wrong with my above verification?

Comment: How do you prove that $\mathscr B_0$ is a subbasis for the topology?

Comment: $\mathscr{B}_0$ is not a subbase unless $M$ is finite.

Comment: What's the point of using $\mathscr U$ instead of $\mathscr V=\{B(x,1):x\in M\}?$ After all, $\mathscr V$ is a subcover of $\mathscr U$; for all you know, your finite subcover $\mathscr B$ is extracted from $\mathscr V.$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I am trying to show that every compact metric space is second countable. At the middle of my proof,I came up with the above argument. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Nil: For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in X\right\}$, and get a finite subcover $\mathscr{B}_n$ of $\mathscr{U}_n$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{B}_n$, and show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable base for $M$.

Comment: Thank you for you excellent suggestion. I helps me lot. Have a good day.

Comment: @Nil: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: would you like to answer this question. otherwise this remains as an unanswered question. I am glad to accept your answer.

Comment: @Nil: Done. $\,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it appears that what you really want to show is that a compact metric space $X$ is second countable. To do that, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\left\{B\left(x,\frac{1}n\right):x\in X\right\}$; $X$ is compact, so $\mathscr{U}_n$ has a finite subcover $\mathscr{B}_n$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{B}_n$; then show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$. This takes a little work with the triangle inequality but isn't too hard.